# How to remove old line when writing new line?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a program that reads 2 files.  If the number in db.csv is larger than the number in log.csv, replace the number in log.csv with the larger number.
Otherwise, do nothing.

The problem with my code is that the smaller number is not being replaced.  The larger number is being written to the file but the smaller number is being appended to the second line.  I want the smaller number to be removed.

Here is my code that actually works:

```
import time
import os

def locate():

    while True:

        time.sleep(8)
        try:
            with open("log.csv", "rb") as f:  # Open local log for read
                for number in f:
                    log_number = number
                    with open("db.csv", "rb") as f2:  # Open db for write

                        # Will read database here
                        for first_line in f2:
                            db_number = first_line

                            if db_number > log_number:
                                print ("We have a new winner!")
                                with open("log.csv", "wb") as f:  # Open local log for write
                                    f.write(db_number)
                                    break
                            else:
                                print ("Number is the same.")
                                break
        except OSError as e:
            print (e)
            break

locate()
```

My problem happens when I try and keep the with open("log.csv") to 1 line.
For example:

```
import time
import os

def locate():

    while True:

        time.sleep(8)
        try:
            with open("log.csv", "rb+") as f:  # Open local log for read
                for number in f:
                    log_number = number
                    with open("db.csv", "rb") as f2:  # Open db for write

                        # Will read database here
                        for first_line in f2:
                            db_number = first_line

                            if db_number > log_number:
                                print ("We have a new winner!")
                                f.truncate()  # trying to remove the old number
                                f.write(db_number)

                                break
                            else:
                                print ("Number is the same.")
                                break
        except OSError as e:
            print (e)
            break

locate()
```

How do I properly remove the old(smaller) number from log.csv?

The old number is written to line 2.

Comment: load your file into memory, alter data, then write the entire thing back maybe easier.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I properly remove the old(smaller) number from log.csv?

after you've written anything after it, you really can't.

That's not how files work!

A file really is only a contiguous array of bytes. You can't "remove some in the middle".

What you need to do is copy all lines before and after the line to be removed.

`truncate()` will remove all contents *after* the line you've just read (that's where the file pointer is at that moment). You'd need to count the length of that line, and do something like `f.truncate(f.tell()-lastlinelength)`. But you'd lose everything after! I don't really think you want what `truncate` does.

All in all, you seem to need to modify a couple of numbers. Just keep that whole list of entries in RAM and write it out after you've read the whole log, and processed it.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to do this or to just open log.csv a second time like in my first code?

Comment: I can't tell you how your OS buffers files, how fast your file system and storage devices are... but assuming we're not talking 100s of megabytes of log, it's probably faster, but not measurable.